Any possibility to draw precisely for below Geometry image?
I have below geometry would like to draw by using tkz-euclide. Here is the description:
Let points A,B,C are the points on the sides of triangle (A1 B1 C1), and ⦟A=⦟A1, ⦟B=⦟B1, ⦟C=⦟C1
How to draw very precisely by latex? This example is not accurate. I know △ABC ∼ △A1B1C1,but I have no idea how to do it. Please kindly help. Thank you!

Here are my code(Now I put each point at the midpoint of each side, but this is only a very special case).
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[lua]{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/B1,5/0/C1,4/4/A1}\tkzDrawPolygon(A1,B1,C1)
    \tkzLabelPoint(B1){$B_1$}\tkzLabelPoint(C1){$C_1$}\tkzLabelPoint[above](A1){$A_1$}
    \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=0.5](B1,C1)\tkzGetPoint{A}\tkzLabelPoints(A)
    \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=0.5](A1,B1)\tkzGetPoint{C}\tkzLabelPoints[left](C)
    \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=0.5](C1,A1)\tkzGetPoint{B}\tkzLabelPoints[right](B)
    \tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
    \tkzFindAngle(B,A,C)\tkzGetAngle{cab}\tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.3](B,A,C){\pgfmathprintnumber{\cab}}
    \tkzFindAngle(B1,A1,C1)\tkzGetAngle{cabo}\tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.3](B1,A1,C1){\pgfmathprintnumber{\cabo}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



I think your question could be improved if you also provided the code that gives the result you show.

Hm, but question about how to geometrically solve this issue are probably better asked at https://math.stackexchange.com or similar sites …

One would think that one could inscribe any triangle inside another, but that isn't the case.  If the inside triangle is too small, you will never be able to intersect all three vectices at the same time..  The midpoint solution is the lower limit.  For equilateral triangles, the upper limit is the outside triangle.  Rotating around the centroid might lead to an easy solution.

I don't know how to use tikz, so here comes something that seems to work in MetaPost(MetaFun). I'm sure you can argue why it works (or not!), and translate to tikz.

The idea is the following: Start with triangle ABC, and mark a point D on the edge BC. In the code ratio determines the ratio BD/BC. Then construct two triangles similar to ABC with the original A corner at D (darkred and darkyellow in the figure). The scaling should be so that when you rotate them the "B corner" ends up at C and A, respectively. These rotated triangles are drawn in darkblue and darkgreen. Then draw the dashed line (that corresponds to the "C corners" of the original triangle. Mark the intersection with AB. That is the point E. Now DE magically seems to be the side we are looking for. So, finally, we just scale and rotate the original triangle so that it goes where we want it. Below you find the code (run with "context file.tex"). We loop over different ratios to test it.
\starttext

\dorecurse{9}{%
  \startMPpage[offset=1DK]
    numeric u ; u := 1cm ;
    numeric ratio ; ratio := #1/10 ;
    path t[] ;

    z0 = origin ;
    z1 = (5u,0) ;
    z2 = (4u,4u) ;
    t0 := z0 -- z1 -- z2 -- cycle ;
    z4 = ratio[z1,z2] ;
    t1 := t0 scaled (((y2 - y4) ++ (x2 - x4))/((y1 - y0) ++ (x1 - x0))) shifted z4 ;
    t2 := t1 rotatedaround(z4, angle (z2 - z4) - angle (z1 - z0)) ;
    t3 := t0 scaled (((y0 - y4) ++ (x0 - x4))/((y1 - y0) ++ (x1 - x0))) shifted z4 ;
    t4 := t3 rotatedaround(z4, angle (z0 - z4) - angle (z1 - z0)) ;
    z5 = ((point 2 of t2) -- (point 2 of t4)) intersectionpoint (z0 -- z1) ;
    t5 := t0 scaled (((y5 - y4) ++ (x5 - x4))/((y0 - y2) ++ (x0 - x2))) shifted z4 ;
    t5 := t5 rotatedaround(z4, angle (z5 - z4) - angle (z2 - z0)) ;

    draw t0 ;
    draw t1 withcolor darkred ;
    draw t2 withcolor darkblue ;
    draw t3 withcolor darkyellow ;
    draw t4 withcolor darkgreen ;
    draw (point 2 of t2) -- (point 2 of t4) dashed evenly ;
    drawpoints z4 && z5 ;
    draw t5 withpen pencircle scaled 1 ;

    label.lft ("\m {A}", z0) ;
    label.rt  ("\m {B}", z1) ;
    label.top ("\m {C}", z2) ;
    label.rt  ("\m {D}", z4) ;
    label.llft("\m {E}", z5) ;
  \stopMPpage
}

\stoptext

All pages from the run:

One example where the angle B is 90 degrees:

One example where B is obtuse:

Addition The construction is not always working. If we replace the definition of z5 into
    z5 = whatever[point 2 of t2,point 2 of t4] = whatever [z0,z1] ;

Then the final triangle can end up outside in failing cases.


I am not familiar with metapost yet, but I will try to take a deep look. Thank you!
